# How to hide elements in dropdownlist with javascript

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-dropdown

I have a problem hiding elements from my dropdownlist.
I have 3 items in that dropdownlist:
"Unknown",
"Female",
"Male"
I want to display just "unknown" when I click to other dropdownlist  personTypeCode = "legal"

I have tried this, but it doesn't work

```
changeIDTypeVisibility: function () {
    personTypeCode = $("#PersonTypeCode").val();
    if (personTypeCode === "legal") {
        $('#FirstName').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
        // $('#LastName').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
        $('#MiddleName').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
        $('#FatherName').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
        $('#MotherName').attr('readonly', 'readonly');

        document.getElementById('selectIdHere').selectedIndex = 0;                                                       
        CRTool.PersonDetails.getGenderElements().each(function (index, element) {

            $('#GenderId').showHideDropdownOptions('2', false);
        });
    }
    else {
        // natural
        CRTool.PersonDetails.getGenderElements().each(function (index, element) {

            $(element).show();
        });
    }
},
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsNatural)
    @if( Model.CanSave )
    {
        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.PersonTypeCode)
        .BindTo(new[] { new { Id = "natural", Name = Resx.PersonDetails.Natural }, new { Id = "legal", Name = Resx.PersonDetails.Legal } })
        .DataTextField("Name")
        .DataValueField("Id")
        .Events(events => events.Change("CRTool.PersonDetails.changeIDTypeVisibility")))
    }
    else
    @if( Model.CanSave )
    {
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.GenderId)
        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.GenderId)
        .BindTo(Model.GenderTypes)
        .DataTextField("Name")
        .DataValueField("Id")        
        )
    }
    else
    {
        if(Model.IsNatural){
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.GenderId)
            <span class="readonly">@Html.DisplayDashFor(m => m.GenderName)</span>
        }
```

```js
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsNatural)
                @if( Model.CanSave )
                {
                    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.PersonTypeCode)
                    .BindTo(new[] { new { Id = "natural", Name = Resx.PersonDetails.Natural }, new { Id = "legal", Name = Resx.PersonDetails.Legal } })
                    .DataTextField("Name")
                    .DataValueField("Id")
                    .Events(events => events.Change("CRTool.PersonDetails.changeIDTypeVisibility")
                        )
                    )
                }




 @if( Model.CanSave )
                {
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.GenderId)
                    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.GenderId)
                    .BindTo(Model.GenderTypes)
                    .DataTextField("Name")
                    .DataValueField("Id")
                    
                    )
                }
                else
                {
                    if(Model.IsNatural){
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.GenderId)
                        <span class="readonly">@Html.DisplayDashFor(m => m.GenderName)</span>
                    }
```

Comment: Please post your HTML-code too

Comment: I edited the post, look at it

Comment: Your appear to have duplicated some code.

Comment: hmm, For me it looks fine, I dont know, maybe the html is duplicated. any solutions?

Comment: There is nothing 'fine' about the code in the question. The last block appears to be a repeat of the code above it. You have not shown any of the functions you refer to (e.g. `getGenderElements()`, `showHideDropdownOptions()`). If you want to hide all but the first option in a `<select>` it simply `$('#GenderId option:not(:first)').hide();` and to show them all its `$('#GenderId option').show();`. And the correct usage is `$('#FirstName').prop('readonly', true);` And why do you have `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.GenderId)` associated with `GenderName`?

Comment: Oh I see it now. But $('#GenderId option:not(:first)').hide(); id doesnt work

Comment: @user2568960, Of course it does. I have tested it.

Comment: hmm, I dont know, it's not working for me in this code, maybe I am missing something

Comment: getGenderElements: function () {
            return $("[for='GenderId']").parent().children();
        }
    };

Comment: What on earth is `return $("[for='GenderId']").parent().children();`? Why do even you have a `getGenderElements()`  function. Look at the code in my second comment - its just `$('#GenderId option:not(:first)').hide();`!

Answer (score 0):

use this code `$('#GenderId').eq(0).hide()`